# paging recyclerView with viewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am trying to add a recycler view in a fragment with viewPage my issue is when activity launched adapter automatically scrolled to bottom and load the second page and append it to list without any interactions from user !!.

adapter bottom listener

```
class PreviousOrdersAdapter(val context: Context, private val listener: OnOrderClickedListener<OrdersModel>,
                        private val pageListener: OnBottomReachedListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PreviousOrdersAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    holder.bind(position)

    if (position == items.size - 1) {
        pageListener.loadMore()
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to handle pagination  in activity or fragment intead of adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to handle it on activity or fragment instead of adapter. because adapter will create visible count +2 views so your pagination api will call many time without user interaction.

```
rv.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrolled(r: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            if (!r.canScrollVertically(1) && dy != 0) {
                //call api for next page
            }
        }
    });
```